# Node JS cookie parser not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies

I am following a tutorial at https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/cookie-management-in-express-js. I want to use cookies in my web app to authenticate requests to an API that I am building with Node JS. To set the cookie when the user logs in, I use this line of code:

```
res.cookie('crewcookie', userkey, { maxAge: 9000000, httpOnly: true });
res.status(200).json({status: 1, data: userdata});
```

Since httpOnly is true, I tried checking for the cookie when another request is made to my API like this:

```
console.log(req.cookies);
```

At the top of my script, I have the following:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

I doesn't seem like it is working because when I check for the cookie in subsequent requests, the log shows this:

```
{}
```

It may be worth mentioning that I am using Angular JS in the front. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is API where you set/check cookie on same domain and port as page being loaded?

Comment: I was not aware that it had to be on the same port. Is there a way to make it same domain only or do I have no other choice?

Comment: if different port then is considered cross domain by browser. To send cookies from client need to use `withCredentials` on all requests. See `$http` docs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with React, and took a while to realize the issue may be with using cookies in the *development* environment vs. production. If you log 'req.cookies' right after setting it, pretty sure you'll see it has been saved - it's just deleted later on (possibly after a redirect).
However, in a production environment, the cookie was set (in my case) and could be retrieved with req.cookies following redirect.
I would add an if statement to the code you need the cookie for, something like this (express):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){...}
```

so that the use of cookies will be carried out in the production environment only.