# Axios- Node JS cookie parser is returning a empty object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I am working on my Project. When I was using Axios I ran into a few problems that I do not get.

Here I saw a similar question that represents my situation:
[Node JS cookie parser not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366457/node-js-cookie-parser-not-working)

Here is my React Code with Axios installed and Imported:

```
useEffect(() => { 
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-cookie')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            
    }, [])
```

And my app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');



const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
require('dotenv').config()






//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


// connecting to database

let gfs;
const uri = process.env.DB
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.once("open", function () {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");

    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection("photos");
});



// cookie routes 
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/set-cookie/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("User_ID",  req.params.id, {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31, httpOnly: true})

  res.json("You setted the cookies")
});



app.get('/get-cookie', (req, res) => {

    var cookies = req.cookies
    res.json(cookies)
});


// custom routes
const notes_router = require('./routes/notes')
const avatar_router = require('./routes/avatar');
const user_router = require('./routes/user');

app.use(avatar_router);
app.use(user_router);
app.use(notes_router);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});

module.exports = gfs
```

I tested these on postman and they worked.
So I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axios by default don't send cookies but you can pass the option `withCredentials` as `true` and it should work

```
useEffect(() => { 
   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/get-cookie',{withCredentials: true})
     .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
     })      
}, [])
```

EDIT: You will have to set the CORS policy on you Express app as well for this to work you can try the below middleware (assuming your react app is running on `localhost:3000`, you can change it match with you):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

Or you can use [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package as well.

Comment: Now I am getting "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)"

Comment: @LohithK. updated the answer please try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Karman When I use the extra code that you put. I still get the same error. But then I see that I have already used the "app.use(cors());" line.  Then I tried to comment the "app.use(cors());" line and use the extra code, it worked but gave an empty object.

Comment: @Karman I have updated the question to show the full app.js code before I added the extra code

Comment: When you are setting the cookie in the `post` call you have to pass `withCredentials: true` there as well to set the cookie.